# Cannot load EDF data in MNE (65 channels instead of 64)

Tags: python, python-3.x, mne-python

In our EEG experiment, we used 64 electrodes plus 1 EOG channel. We're trying to read it using the MNE package but run into an error. Looks like MNE expects 64 channels by default?

```
raw = read_raw_edf(input_fname=data_file,
                   eog=['EOG'],
                   preload=True)
```

Gives us this error:

```
IndexError: index 65 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 64
```

How do we avoid it? Should we set the montage ourselves, to overwrite the expected 64-channel montage?

Answer (score 0):

Requirement: your size of index looks like 64 electrodes + 1 EOG Channel = total 65

Issue: MNE can be declared till 64 ,so outer than that is out of bound index size (in your case 65 is out of bound),

Plausible Solution: Please make sure Size of index is also declared from 0 (if it was 1)to 64 !

Comment: But how? I would love to tell MNE what channels to expect, but I have no idea where. Also, MNE can handle 128 channels just fine, so I don't see the problem here.

Comment: Can you please share print(raw.info) ; and try if you can see data in MNE

Comment: Since the function yields an error, nothing is returned, and the raw variable is not created.

Comment: Try This: import mne
filename = "myfile.edf"
raw = mne.io.read_raw_edf(filename)
raw_data = data.get_data()
raw_channels = data.ch_names , rawinfo = raw.info()

Comment: This gives the same error. The read_raw_edf function fails. None of the other lines can work, since ‘raw’ is never created. I assume ‘data’ is meant to be ‘raw’ in your code.

Comment: Sorry can you edit that and try; raw_data = raw.get_data()

Comment: Also please refer mne samples for read_raw_edf() : https://mne.tools/dev/generated/mne.io.read_raw_edf.html

Comment: I feel like there's a miscommunication here. The first call (read_raw_edf) fails, so there is never a 'raw' variable/object. I cannot execute methods on an object that is never created.